Why is the AWS lambda event empty when invoking with a Test event json?
A lambda function is invoked with the following test event json
{ 
    "date":"2024-05-17 13:14:15",
}

The lambda_handler transfers execution to an internal method including the context:
        return handler(event, context)

I added print(event) in the handler and it shows the event as empty:
def get_call_metrics(event, context):
    query_params = event.get('queryStringParameters', {})
    print("query_params", query_params)

In Cloudwatch:

query_params {}

So then how is this test event json supposed to be used/how does it work?

It doesn't show the event as empty. It shows the event's queryStringParameters as empty/absent. Your test event doesn't have queryStringParameters. I recommend that you invoke the Lambda function via API Gateway initially and have your Lambda function simply print the entire event so you can see how it's constructed. Then use that as a template for your test event.

I suppose that you mean Testing Lambda functions in the console.
The JSON you put into the test call is the event parameter in your handler function. So if you actually print(event) instead of accessing queryStringParameters on the event when you don't provide it in the test-object, it will print exactly what you passed in.
So what you probably want to do is recreate the event of the service that will trigger this lambda, e.g., the Event format for REST APIs.
Additionally, the aws console has event templates for several services.

Lots of new things for me here and there are a number of hidden behaviors in AWs. I thought queryStringParameters were some kind of builtin.
